# Defining a variable range of cells

Tags: vba, excel

I have a problem in defining a variable range of cells. The problematic line is denoted by two stars from each end. Just below it there are some commented lines that I've also tried with no success. Public Sub Dreiecke_gleichen() works fine, I've only included it such that you could see what a "sheetvektor" is.

Finally, any suggestions of how I could improve the code, s.t., experienced programmers don't faint when they read it? =)

Huge thank you in advance,

```
Option Explicit
Private sheetvektor() As String

Public Sub Dreiecke_gleichen()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim Blatt1, Blatt2 As String
Dim Anfangsjahr1, Anfangsjahr2 As Integer
Dim reporting_Jahr1, reporting_Jahr2 As String
Dim i As Integer

i = 1

For Each ws In Worksheets

    If ws.Name Like "RVA_H*" Then
            ReDim Preserve sheetvektor(i)
            sheetvektor(i) = ws.Name

            If IsEmpty(Blatt1) = False Then
            Blatt2 = ws.Name
            Anfangsjahr2 = ws.Range("A3").Value
            reporting_Jahr2 = ws.Range("A1").Value
            i = i + 1
            Else
            Blatt1 = ws.Name
            Anfangsjahr1 = ws.Cells(3, 1).Value
            reporting_Jahr1 = ws.Cells(1, 1).Value
            i = i + 1
            GoTo X
            End If
    Else: GoTo X
    End If

    If reporting_Jahr1 <> reporting_Jahr2 Then
       MsgBox "Dreiecke von unterschiedlichen Jahren"
       Exit Sub

    ElseIf reporting_Jahr1 = reporting_Jahr2 Then

        If Anfangsjahr1 < Anfangsjahr2 Then
        Worksheets(Blatt2).Rows("3:" & 3 + Anfangsjahr2 - Anfangsjahr1 - 1).Insert


        ElseIf Anfangsjahr1 > Anfangsjahr2 Then
        Worksheets(Blatt1).Rows("3:" & 3 + Anfangsjahr1 - Anfangsjahr2 - 1).Insert

        ElseIf Anfangsjahr1 = Anfangsjahr2 Then GoTo X
        End If


   End If

   X: Next ws

   End Sub

Public Sub Dreiecksummieren()

Dim j, n As Integer
Dim lastcol, lastrow As Integer
Dim grosematrix() As Variant
Dim myrange As String


        If IsEmpty(sheetvektor()) = True Then
            MsgBox "Solche Blätter existieren nicht"
        Else
            j = 3

            Do While IsEmpty(Worksheets(sheetvektor(1)).Cells(j, 1)) = True
            j = j + 1
            Loop

            lastcol = Worksheets(sheetvektor(1)).Cells(j, 1).End(xlToRight).Column
            lastrow = Worksheets(sheetvektor(1)).Cells(j, 1).End(xlDown).Row

        End If


For n = 1 To UBound(sheetvektor)

**    grosematrix(n) = Worksheets(sheetvektor(n)).Range(Cells(j, 1), Cells(lastrow, lastcol)).Value  **

'    grosematrix(n) = Worksheets(sheetvektor(n)).Range("A" & j: Cells(lastrow, lastcol)).Value

'     grosematrix(n) = Worksheets(sheetvektor(n)).Range(Cells(j, 1).Address(), Cells(lastrow, lastcol).Address()).Value

'    Let myrange = "Cells(j, 1), Cells(lastrow, lastcol)"
'    Let grosematrix(n) = Worksheets(sheetvektor(n)).Range(myrange).Value
Next n

Debug.Print (WorksheetFunction.Sum(grosematrix))

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you must resolve yourself to update a "groseSum" sheet by sheet

furthermore I tried to grasp the logic of your code and here's what I came up to

```
Option Explicit

Private sheetvektor As Collection

Public Sub Dreiecke_gleichen2()

Dim wsRef As Worksheet, ws As Worksheet
Dim Blatt1 as string, Blatt2 As String
Dim Anfangsjahr1 as integer, Anfangsjahr2 As Integer
Dim reporting_Jahr1 as string, reporting_Jahr2 As String
Dim iWs As Integer


Set sheetvektor = GetSheets(ActiveWorkbook, "RVA_H*") ' get all "wanted" worksheets of the active workbook whose name matches the given one

If sheetvektor.Count = 0 Then Exit Sub ' if no "wanted" worksheets then exit sub

Set wsRef = sheetvektor.Item(1) ' set the first "wanted" worksheet as the reference one
With wsRef 'get reference values
    Blatt1 = .Name
    Anfangsjahr1 = .Cells(3, 1).Value
    reporting_Jahr1 = .Cells(1, 1).Value
End With

For iWs = 2 To sheetvektor.Count

    Set ws = sheetvektor.Item(iWs)
    With ws
        Blatt2 = .Name
        Anfangsjahr2 = .Cells(3, 1).Value
        reporting_Jahr2 = .Cells(1, 1).Value
    End With

    If reporting_Jahr1 <> reporting_Jahr2 Then

       MsgBox "Dreiecke von unterschiedlichen Jahren"
       Exit For

    Else

        If Anfangsjahr1 < Anfangsjahr2 Then
            ws.Rows("3:" & 3 + Anfangsjahr2 - Anfangsjahr1 - 1).Insert

        ElseIf Anfangsjahr1 > Anfangsjahr2 Then
            wsRef.Rows("3:" & 3 + Anfangsjahr1 - Anfangsjahr2 - 1).Insert
        End If

    End If

Next iWs

Call Dreiecksummieren

End Sub


Function GetSheets(wb As Workbook, shtNameLike As String) As Collection
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim wss As New Collection

For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
    If ws.Name Like shtNameLike Then wss.Add ws
Next ws

Set GetSheets = wss

End Function



Public Sub Dreiecksummieren()

Dim lastcol As Integer, lastrow As Integer, j As Integer
Dim refAdress As String
Dim groseSum As Double

If sheetvektor.Count = 0 Then
    MsgBox "Solche Blätter existieren nicht"
    Exit Sub
End If

With sheetvektor(1)
    j = 3
    If IsEmpty(.Cells(j, 1)) Then j = .Cells(j, 1).End(xlDown).Row

    lastcol = .Cells(j, 1).End(xlToRight).Column ' warning: if there's no values on the right you'll hit the last column of the sheet...
    lastrow = .Cells(j, 1).End(xlDown).Row ' warning: if there's no values down you'll hit the last row of the sheet.... if there's at least one value down the column followed by an empty cell, you'll miss the rows following that empty cell

End With

refAdress = Range(Cells(j, 1), Cells(lastrow, lastcol)).Address
groseSum = 0
For j = 1 To sheetvektor.Count
    groseSum = groseSum + WorksheetFunction.Sum(sheetvektor(j).Range(refAdress))
Next j

Debug.Print (groseSum)

End Sub
```

and here follows an alternative for using `grosematrix()`, which comes out as a "vector of matrices", where at its index "i" you'll place the contents of a 2D range.

thus `grosematrix(3)(2,3)` will return the content of cell (2,3) relative to the chosen range (which in turn can be some "A3:H9", so its cell (2,3) is actually "C4") of the third worksheet filtered out of all the workbooks ones.

since you can't give a 3D element as the argument of `WorksheetFunction.Sum`, you still must update a groseSum while iterating through every worksheet of `sheetvektor`

```
Public Sub Dreiecksummieren2()

Dim lastcol As Integer, lastrow As Integer, j As Integer
Dim refAdress As String
Dim grosematrix() As Variant
Dim groseSum As Double

If sheetvektor.Count = 0 Then
    MsgBox "Solche Blätter existieren nicht"
    Exit Sub
End If

With sheetvektor(1)
    j = 3
    If IsEmpty(.Cells(j, 1)) Then j = .Cells(j, 1).End(xlDown).Row

    lastcol = .Cells(j, 1).End(xlToRight).Column ' warning: if there's no values on the right you'll hit the last column of the sheet...
    lastrow = .Cells(j, 1).End(xlDown).Row ' warning: if there's no values down you'll hit the last row of the sheet.... if there's at least one value down the column followed by an empty cell, you'll miss the rows following that empty cell
End With
refAdress = Range(Cells(j, 1), Cells(lastrow, lastcol)).Address

groseSum = 0
ReDim grosematrix(1 To sheetvektor.Count)
For j = 1 To sheetvektor.Count
    grosematrix(j) = sheetvektor(j).Range(refAdress)
    groseSum = groseSum + WorksheetFunction.Sum(grosematrix(j))
Next j

Debug.Print (groseSum)

End Sub
```

As for the logic, assuming I did get your actual one (which I'm not so sure of...) , I think you must refine it to catch exceptions (no proper/minimum number of sheets meeting criteria, proper definition of data range to take into account...)

Answer (score 0):

I would try removing some `()`:

```
Dim grosematrix As Variant   'no ()
...
grosematrix = Worksheets(sheetvektor(n)).Range(Cells(j, 1), Cells(lastrow, lastcol))
```

Comment: I incorporated your suggestions but, unfortunately, it still gets stuck at the same line "grosematrix = Worksheets..." by saying "Application-defined or object-defined error". =(

Comment: Besides, may I kindly ask, if by removing the brackets I am still going to be able to store a vector of variables, i.e., grosematrix(1); grosematrix(2), etc?

Comment: try assigning something simple, like `grosematrix=sheet1.range("b2:c5")`, you will see at least if the error comes from the left side or the right side of the equal sign.